# Building a response array after binding parameters for PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to build the array that will return to my ajax success. How do I build the array after binding it to something like :some variable.

The following script runs to completion, and inserts with no problem into sql. But the variables comment and transaction come back as null in the response. I think the problem is using $comment and $transaction when building the array. What is the right way to reference these values in the array?

```
        require('../dbcon2.php');
        //Connection 1
        try {
          $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE listings SET comment = :comment, transaction = :transaction, ad_link = :ad_link WHERE id = :id");
            // Bind
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $_POST['comment']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':transaction', $_POST['transaction']);
          $stmt->execute();
          // Build array
           $response = array
                 ('state'  => 200, "success" => true, "id" => ':id', "comment" => $comment, "transaction" => $transaction 
                 );
          exit(json_encode($response));

        }
    catch (Exception $e) {
                // create a asociative array
                $data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e.getMessage());
                // encode data and exit.
                exit(json_encode($data));
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the `$_POST` variable? That contains the values you need and you use them already in your database query.

Comment: ^ that, or do/try as you did for `:id` - `"id" => ':id', "comment" => ':comment', "transaction" => ':transaction'`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i get a syntax error in my html writer when I do that though?

Comment: @Fred-ii- no i don 't , sorry, testing

Comment: You're welcome Rhillz. *Cheers* (it has been done).

Comment: @Rhillz What do you mean, *both work*? What is the response you expect to get back?

Comment: using _post and using my bound paramter :id, both of these methods show the response value in my browser dev tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's wish:

Do as you did for `"id" => ':id'`

```
"id" => ':id', "comment" => ':comment', "transaction" => ':transaction'
```

Plus, quoting Jeroen (kudos to)

*Why don't you use the `$_POST` variable? That contains the values you need and you use them already in your database query.*

Comment: Um, how would that get the actual values in the response array? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @jeroen She's already getting the right values from the binds. She did say that both methods worked.

Comment: But the response will just contain the strings `:id`, etc., no actual values. And yes, I seriously doubt that statement by the OP :-)

Comment: @jeroen Maybe she's doing something we don't know? I'd be happy to delete my answer. Maybe ask her?

Comment: @jeroen She didn't mention about id not coming through, therefore for me, it only made sense that the bind for id was successful, and that in following the same method would work for the others. However, by using the POST method as you suggested, would theoretically round off to the same thing, wouldn't it? After all, the `':id', $_POST['id'])` is successful as per the other two being entered in DB. `"success" => true, "id" => ':id'` binded responses. So, `$comment` and `$transaction` are only variables not yet bound.

Comment: But the parameter is bound just in the sql statement, there is no magical constant `':id'` that you can use throughout your code. These are just strings but if it works for the OP...

Comment: @jeroen As you said, must be some *voodoo* code happening lol

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve bound values after calling `->bindParam()`; also, the variables `$comment` and `$transaction` aren't defined (unless you set them yourself or when using voodoo php settings).

That said, you already know those values:

```
$response = array(
   'state'        => 200, 
    "success"     => true, 
    "id"          => $_POST['id'], 
    "comment"     => $_POST['comment'], 
    "transaction" => $_POST['transaction'], 
);
```

Btw, in the exception branch you have a small bug:

```
$data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e.getMessage());
                                                                   ^
```

You should use `$e->getMessage()` instead.